# How do I get high scores for each player from a list which has many dictionaries? Each dict is a name and a score

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The list of dictionaries is stored as score_list

The data stored within score_list is:

```
[{'LLCoolDave': '23'}, {'LLCoolDave': '27'}, {'red': '12'}, {'LLCoolDave': '26'}, {'tom123': '26'}, {'O_O': '7'}, {'Misha46': '24'}, {'O_O': '14'}, {'Empiro': '18'}, {'Empiro': '18'}, {'MaxxT': '25'}, {'L33tH4x': '42'}, {'Misha46': '25'}, {'johnsmith': '30'}, {'Empiro': '23'}, {'O_O': '22'}, {'MaxxT': '25'}, {'Misha46': '24'}]
```

When I do

```
scores = {}
for i in score_list:
    scores.update(i)
print(scores)
```

it only gives me one key value pair of each player, even though some players have more than one score.

How can I get this into a form where I can get the highest score of each player from the data?

The desired output I am looking for is:

```
Empiro 23
L33tH4x 42
LLCoolDave 27
MaxxT 25
Misha46 25
O_O 22
johnsmith 30
red 12
tom123 26
```

Comment: We need to see sample data and the desired output. Right now we can only guess about what you want.

Comment: @timgeb sure, I added that.Hope this helps make my question clearer?

Comment: You need to check if a player is already in the scores dictionary and, if so, modify that dictionary only if the score of the dictionary you are processing is higher than the score you have already recorded for that player.

Comment: @timgeb I added the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Take this as a learning reference for your question

```
p_data = [{'LLCoolDave':'23'}, {'LLCoolDave':'27'}, {'red':'12'}, {'LLCoolDave':'26'}, {'tom123':'26'}, {'O_O':'7'}, {'Misha46':'24'}, {'O_O':'14'}, {'Empiro':'18'}, {'Empiro':'18'}, {'MaxxT':'25'}, {'L33tH4x':'42'}, {'Misha46':'25'}, {'johnsmith':'30'}, {'Empiro':'23'}, {'O_O':'22'}, {'MaxxT':'25'}, {'Misha46':'24'}]

res = {}
for i in p_data:                                # loop through each data
    for j, v in i.items():                      # get key value pair of each team
        res[j] = res.get(j, 0)                  # assign it with 0 if its first time for the result dict.
        v = int(v)                              # converting value to int for comparision
        res[j] = v if res[j] < v else res[j]    # comapre with previous value 

print(res)                                      # print result

# Result =  {'LLCoolDave': 27, 'red': 12, 'tom123': 26, 'O_O': 22, 'Misha46': 25, 'Empiro': 23, 'MaxxT': 25, 'L33tH4x': 42, 'johnsmith': 30}
```